# Updated to Angular 1.3.0 no longer working

Tags: javascript, angularjs, browserify

I am using `Browserify` to wrap everything up. I have just upgraded from `1.2.23` to `1.3.0` and am now getting the following errors:

**Firefox Error**

```
TypeError: angular.module is not a function

var app = angular.module('login-Controller', ['Views']);
   ----------^
```

Clearly says that angular is not defined. So I outputed the output from angular

```
var angular = require('angular'),
console.info(angular); // Object {} ='s an empty object
```

Does this mean that angular is no longer compatible with `browserify`? If it is, how can I get it working?

**Detailed Error from Chrome**

```
 Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function main.js:25868 C:\var\www\stage.mayfieldafc.com\src\site\js\users\loginCntrl.js.angularmain.js:1 smain.js:1 (anonymous function)main.js:28 ./src/site/js/app.js.angularmain.js:1 smain.js:1 emain.js:1 (anonymous function)
main.js:183 Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module mays due to:
Error: [$injector:nomod] Module 'mays' is not available! You either misspelled the module name or forgot to load it. If registering a module ensure that you specify the dependencies as the second argument.
http://errors.angularjs.org/1.3.0/$injector/nomod?p0=mays
    at http://localhost:3000/js/main.js:183:12
    at http://localhost:3000/js/main.js:1900:17
    at ensure (http://localhost:3000/js/main.js:1824:38)
    at module (http://localhost:3000/js/main.js:1898:14)
    at http://localhost:3000/js/main.js:4167:22
    at forEach (http://localhost:3000/js/main.js:438:20)
    at loadModules (http://localhost:3000/js/main.js:4151:5)
    at createInjector (http://localhost:3000/js/main.js:4077:11)
    at doBootstrap (http://localhost:3000/js/main.js:1587:20)
    at bootstrap (http://localhost:3000/js/main.js:1608:12)
http://errors.angularjs.org/1.3.0/$injector/modulerr?p0=mays&p1=Error%3A%20…at%20bootstrap%20(http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A3000%2Fjs%2Fmain.js%3A1608%3A12)main.js:183 (anonymous function)main.js:4190 (anonymous function)main.js:438 forEachmain.js:4151 loadModulesmain.js:4077 createInjectormain.js:1587 doBootstrapmain.js:1608 bootstrapmain.js:1502 angularInitmain.js:25682 (anonymous function)main.js:2845 triggermain.js:3116 eventHandler
```

**Markup**

```
 html(ng-app='mays)
```

Comment: I'm having this exact same problem with Angular 1.3 and Browserify. The Angular object is empty, so then the call to `angular.module` is undefined. It seems like the version of Angular downloaded by npm doesn't export anything. Any resolution yet?

Comment: Ye thats the exact problem. I'll add the answer to how i fixed it. Its a bloody horrible horrible... horrible hac KD:

Answer (score 12, accepted):

As mentioned by @JeffB, you can use `browserify-shim` to (hopefully temporarily) remedy this problem.

First, `npm install --save-dev browserify-shim`. Then, add the following to your `package.json`:

```
"browserify": {
    "transform": [
      "browserify-shim"
    ]
  },
  "browser": {
    "angular": "./node_modules/angular/angular.js"
  },
  "browserify-shim": {
    "angular": "angular"
  }
```

This should then let you `require` and access Angular as expected.

Comment: That means you have to remove it from the packages otherwise you'll get a conflict in names.. :/

Comment: @JamieHutber I'm not sure what you mean? I have this working in a project right now with no further changes

Comment: This worked for me given the same error. Thanks so much!

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that angular haven't updated their npm packages to be compatible with browserify just yet.

My fix was disgusting but its working. I simply downloaded `v1.3.0` and pasted it into:

```
 node_modules\angular\lib\angular.min.js
```

Now browserify will compile and use the latest version. This I hope is a temporary fix until they update the package.

Comment: Can't you use browserify-shim instead of doing this? That's what I'm doing with 1.3.

Comment: I got a conflict in names when shimming it.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're defining the module name to be 'login-Controller' in your script, but calling it 'mays' in your markup. I would expect to see something like this:

```
//declare app in main.js
angular.module('name-of-app', [<modules>])

<!-- call your app in markup -->
<html ng-app="name-of-app"></html>

//jade
html(ng-app='name-of-app')
```

Comment: I don't think this is the problem. This is certainly *A* problem, but I believe it's unrelated to the fact that the Angular object is empty after required by Browserify.